# Summarize matrix of boolean variables

Tags: r

I have a bunch of Boolean variables. I want to summarize them and show the percentage of positive values. The **big thing** in this question is that the variables are logical organized in two dimensions.

The result I want should look like this (kind of):

```
      a    b
v1_1 30%  60%
v1_2 60%  50%
```

Here is a minimal working (self running) example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(v1_1_a = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 v1_1_b = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 v1_2_a = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 v1_2_b = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=TRUE))

my_percent <- function (col) { return (100 / length(col) * sum(col)) }

p <- apply(df, 2, my_percent)

print(p)
```

This is the **output**:

```
v1_1_a v1_1_b v1_2_a v1_2_b 
    30     60     60     50
```

Just for information: The real data has 80 Boolean variables *logical* organized in a 10 x 8 matrix.

Comment: `matrix(colMeans(df), 2, byrow = TRUE)`.

Comment: @lmo The output looks like expected. But `Means` is not `%`. Can you explain this?

Comment: With binary data, the mean is the proportion of 1s.

Comment: @lmo please transform your comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having to add in the row and column names, you could use `colMeans` together with the `matrix` construction function to build a matrix with the desired structure.

```
myMat <- matrix(colMeans(df), 2, byrow = TRUE)
MyMat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.3  0.6
[2,]  0.6  0.5
```

If desired, you could add the names using `dimnames`. In this instance,

```
dimnames(myMat) <- list(paste0("V1", 1:2), letters[1:2])
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could break up the metric names into separate columns.

With dplyr and tidyr:

```
 p <- data.frame(p)

 p$metric <- row.names(p)

 p %>% mutate(metric_1 = ifelse(grepl('v1_1_', metric), "v1_1", "v1_2"),
         metric_2 = ifelse(grepl('a', metric), 'a', 'b')) %>%
   select(-metric) %>%
   spread(key = metric_2, value = p)
```

Giving...

```
   metric_1  a  b
 1     v1_1 30 60
 2     v1_2 60 50
```

You could set the row names to get exactly what you want:

```
 row.names(p) <- p$metric_1
 p %<>% select(-metric_1)
```

Resulting in...

```
       a  b
 v1_1 30 60
 v1_2 60 50
```